# PLS- 00103 encountered the symbol "/" and "Create"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have problem with that PLS-00103 because i completly dont know what to do with that... It looks so simply, and still making problems...

i had problem in first time with PLS-00103 "CREATE" word, and when i put that "/" in third line i got problem with PLS-00103 "/". What am i doing wrong?

```
create or replace package Sappe as
       Procedure initialize;
end;
/

create or replace package body Sappe as

  Procedure initialize is
  begin
    Drop table AAA;

    CREATE TABLE AAA(id int not null,
                     x1 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x2 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x3 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x4 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x5 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x6 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x7 varchar(1) default ' ');

  end initialize;
end sappe;
/
```

Comment: i just want to create table in procedure. but got errors

Comment: What client are you using to run your code?

Answer (score 4):

We can't do native DDL in PL/SQL. You will have to use dynamic SQL:

```
create or replace package body Sappe as

  Procedure initialize is
  begin
    execute immediate 'Drop table AAA';

    execute immediate 
          q'[CREATE TABLE AAA(id int not null,
                     x1 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x2 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x3 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x4 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x5 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x6 varchar(1) default ' ',
                     x7 varchar(1) default ' ')]';

     end initialize;
end sappe;
/
```

Your procedure will fail at the first step if you don't already a table `AAA`. There are various ways of solving this (such as checking USER_TABLES) but the basic premise of stored procedures like this is basically flawed. Outside of a few highly-specialized use cases there is no need to drop and create tables in PL/SQL. It is a common anti-pattern amongst people who are more familiar with other RDBMS products than with Oracle.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, @Potato, because this code works just fine. By the way, why do you set a default value to a space character? What good does it do?

Comment: @Littlefoot i just testing refferences to tables, it's useless table, just want to create some package.

Comment: Yee it complied, but when i try to make begin sappe.initialize(); end; it's not working and i have error with "execute immediate"

Comment: Which one; there are 2 of them. I presume the first one, which drops the table. As APC has told you, it will fail if table doesn't exist.

Comment: @Littlefoot i put comment there, only that "create table" stay on it place, and still have errors while im trying to initalize.

Comment: I've added another answer to your question which show that it *works*. Have a look, please. If it still dosn't work properly on your database, edit your initial message and add copy/paste of your own SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Answer (score 2):

This is too much code to put into a comment so I'm writing it here.

First, checking whether a table exists or not:

```
SQL> DESC aaa;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object aaa does not exist
```

Now, creating a package and its body - I've included control which will prevent error if table doesn't exist:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Sappe
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE initialize;
  4  END;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Sappe
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE initialize
  4     IS
  5        l_cnt   NUMBER;
  6     BEGIN
  7        SELECT COUNT (*)
  8          INTO l_cnt
  9          FROM user_tables
 10         WHERE table_name = 'AAA';
 11
 12        IF l_cnt > 0
 13        THEN
 14           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Drop table AAA';
 15        END IF;
 16
 17        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[CREATE TABLE AAA(id int not null,
 18                       x1 varchar(1) default ' ',
 19                       x2 varchar(1) default ' ',
 20                       x3 varchar(1) default ' ',
 21                       x4 varchar(1) default ' ',
 22                       x5 varchar(1) default ' ',
 23                       x6 varchar(1) default ' ',
 24                       x7 varchar(1) default ' ')]';
 25     END initialize;
 26  END sappe;
 27  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     sappe.initialize;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> DESC aaa;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 X1                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X2                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X3                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X4                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X5                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X6                                                 VARCHAR2(1)
 X7                                                 VARCHAR2(1)

SQL>
```

As you can see, it works. Table now exists, so - let's run the procedure once again - shouldn't fail:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     sappe.initialize;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.